# How to align one tag with another multi-line tag?

Tags: html, css

This is the basic outline of my code:

```html
<div>
  <h6>Heading 6</h6>
  <p>- Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line.</p>
</div>
```

I want to make the render look like this:

> Heading 6 - Long paragraph text that needs
> to wrap to the next line.

I know that styling the `<h6>` and `<p>` with `display: inline-block` will get them on the same line if the text in `<p>` is short, but otherwise, the text in `<p>` won't break to the next line even if I add `word-break: break-word`.

I tried adding `display: flex` to the `<div>`, but this also didn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should add width or max-width property to your div or your p tag

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just tried it, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

use `float` and `shape-outside` properties.

**P.S.** Although `shape-outside` property is not needed in this case but it can be used to customize the text wrapping.

```css
p, h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

h6 {
  float: left;
  shape-outside: padding-box;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h6>Heading 6</h6>
  <p>
    Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that
    needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. - Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to
    the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line. Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: your shape-outside value is invalid, remove it and the result will be kept the same (it's not needed)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I realized my mistake. Changed it from `inset` to `padding-box`. I know its not needed, i only mentioned it in-case OP wants to wrap text around objects other than just simple boxes and also to provide an option to customize the wrapping. Anyways, i have edited my answer to mention that in this case `shape-outside` property is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can set both the heading and the paragraph to display inline.

```css
h6, p {
    display: inline;
}
```

This should wrap the paragraph around the heading.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    div {
    width: 50%;
    }

    p {
      display: inline;
    }

    h6 {
      font-size: 18px;
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <h6>Heading 6</h6>
      <p>
      - Long paragraph text that needs to wrap to the next line.
      </p>
    </div>
```